# DataGridView column order does not work properly

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, windows

I have a datagridview and in the constructor I bind the Datagrid value as data table.

I am changing the column's order in runtime. Some columns I hide and some columns I have rearranged. (Columns are dynamic. Sometimes I have 10 and sometimes I have 20 columns)

Hide columns are invisible. which is fine. But the rearranged columns are not in the correct order.

Am I missing anything here?

Here is my code:

```
    Public Class()
    {
        myGrid.DataSource = gridDataTable;
    }


    List<int> columnsOrder;           //Order index values
    List<string> columnNameFromExcel; // Hiding column strings

    private void VisibleColumns()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            //Hiding columns based on some logics
            if(!columnNameFromExcel.Values.Contains(myGrid.Columns[i].DataPropertyName))
            {
                myGrid.Columns[i].Visible = false;
            }

            //Changing the display index               

             myGrid.Columns[i].DisplayIndex = columnsOrder[i];
        }
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Actual Result:
Column3 Column4 Column5 Column1 Column2

Expected Result:
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
```

Note: 
I have edited my question to avoid confusion. Assigning the display index is fine. I checked it in runtime. There is no duplicate. But still, some column's order did not properly arrange after the execution.

Comment: It is unclear what `some condition` is and what `columnsOrder` contains? Assuming it contains the order for ALL the columns Example: element 0 in the list is the display index for column 0, element1 is column 1 display index… etc.., then why are you looping through this list. Would not simply setting `MyGrid.Columns[i].DisplayIndex  = columnsOrder[i];` …work?

Comment: Again, it is unclear exactly what BOTH lists contain. I would have to guess the `columnsOrder` list would have to contain ALL the columns, otherwise how would you know which columns the ints refer to? The visible columns on the other hand could be a list of ONLY the columns you want to make invisible.

Comment: I have edited my question to avoid confusion. Assigning the display index is fine. I checked it in runtime. There is no duplicate. But still, some columns order not properly arranged after the execution

Comment: I am very confused on WHAT is not correct. Your last comment makes no sense. _”Assigning the display index is fine. I checked it in runtime. There is no duplicate. But still, some columns order not properly arranged after the execution”_... If the Display indexes are fine… The how can the column orders be incorrect?

Comment: I recommend you set the `DisplayIndex` FIRST, then hide the columns. You are hiding the columns FIRST then setting the `DispalyIndex`... if this doesn’t work then you should show an example of what `columnsOrder` and `columnNameFromExcel` List’s contain. Otherwise, how are we to know what those values are?

Answer (score 1):

Responding to an old post/question, I tried turning off the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the datagridview before assigning the `DisplayIndex` and that worked for me.

```
dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgv1.Columns["column1HeaderText"].DisplayIndex = 0;
dgv1.Columns["column2HeaderText"].DisplayIndex = 1;
dgv1.Columns["column3HeaderText"].DisplayIndex = 2;
```

One suggestion is that if there are some columns/any column that has to be hidden then hide it after setting the display index.

```
dgv1.Columns["column1HeaderText"].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to make the order of column using DisplayIndex ,

```
private void makeColumnOrder()
{
    customersDataGridView.Columns["Column1"].DisplayIndex = 0;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["Column2"].DisplayIndex = 1;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["Column3"].DisplayIndex = 2;
}
```

Comment: It will run in a loop. Also, the values are dynamic. I can't assign static value. I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: even thogh values are dynamic the columns are going to be the same.

Comment: The column itself is dynamic. Sometimes I have 10 and sometimes I have 20. What I need is, I have to rearrange the column in a runtime

Comment: When you access the column you can set the displayindex as well

Comment: I have edited my question to avoid confusion. Assigning the display index is fine. I checked it in runtime. There is no duplicate. But still, some columns order not properly arranged after the execution

Answer (score 0):

DisplayIndex is unique, so 2 rows cannot have the same displayIndex. Assumed that it seems rows are created before being reordered, so when you move a row before the other it result in a shift. This happens if 2 columns have Column[A].Index > Column[B].Index and you need to have Column[A].DisplayIndex < Column[B].DisplayIndex

I fixed reverting the order the rows were analyzed. In your example changing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.ColumnCount; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = myGrid.ColumnCount -1; i >= 0; i--)
```